# Recursive expression whose only base case is an exception [Context: Reading from files in OCaml]

Tags: file-io, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

***Edit:  Disregard this question!  See comments below.***

I want an OCaml expression which is passed a file (as an "in_channel"), then reads the file line by line, doing some processing, to the end, then returns the result of the processing.

I wrote this test:

```
let rec sampler_string file string_so_far =
    try 
        let line = input_line file in
        let first_two_letters = String.sub line 0 2 in
        sampler_string file (string_so_far ^ first_two_letters)
    with End_of_file -> string_so_far;;

let a = sampler_string (open_in Sys.argv.(1)) "";;
```

(Here the "doing some processing" is adding the first two characters of each line to a running tally, and the idea is that at the end a string containing the first two characters of every line should be returned.)

This doesn't work:  **OCaml thinks that "sampler_string" produces something of type unit, rather than of type string**.  (Difficulties then occur later when I try to use the result as a string.)  I think this problem is because **the only base case happens in an exception** (the End_of_file).

So, a specific question and a general question:

1. Is there a way to fix this code, by explicitly telling OCaml to expect that the result of sampler_string should be a string?
2. Is there some standard, better syntax for a routine which reads a file line by line to the end, and returns the result of line-by-line processing?

Comment: This is what OCaml 3.12 says of your function definition here: `val sampler_string : in_channel -> string -> string = <fun>`... looks ok to me

Comment: Hi @Damien, you're totally right.  I misunderstood the source of an error.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Damien Pollet says, your sampler_string function compiles fine (and runs correctly) on my machine as well, ocaml v3.12.0. However, I'll answer your questions:

1. You can specify types on your functions/values using the `:` operator. For example, here's your function with it's types annotated. You'll notice that the return type is put at the very end of the function declaration.

   ```
   let rec sampler_string (file : in_channel) (string_so_far : string) : string = ...
   ```
2. I do not know if there's a better way of reading a file, line-by-line. It certainly is a pain to be forced to deal with an end-of-file via exception. [Here's a blog post on the subject](http://camltastic.blogspot.com/2008/09/tip-read-all-lines-from-file-most.html), though the function presented there is of reading a file into a list of lines. [Another mailing list version](http://groups.google.com/group/fa.caml/msg/0e938e47479af474?pli=1).

A couple of nitpicks:

1. You don't need to use `;;` to separate function/value definitions, ocamlc can figure it out from whitespace.
2. You should close your file sockets.
3. String.sub will throw an exception if your file has a line with less than 2 characters.

Comment: You'll see I've simultaneously noticed this post was misguided.  But thanks for the helpful code critique, and the links.

Answer (score 2):

A major point of style is avoiding recursive calls inside an exception handler. Such calls are *not* in tail position, so you will blow the stack with a sufficiently large file. Use this pattern instead:

```
let rec sampler_string file string_so_far =
  match try Some (input_line file) with End_of_file -> None with
  | Some line ->
      let first_two_letters = String.sub line 0 2 in
      sampler_string file (string_so_far ^ first_two_letters)
  | None -> string_so_far
```

Of course a better functional strategy is to abstract away the recursive schema:

```
let rec fold_left_lines f e inch =
  match try Some (input_line inch) with End_of_file -> None with
  | Some line -> fold_left_lines f (f e line) inch
  | None -> e
```

since "doing things with the lines of a file" is a generally useful operation in and of itself (counting lines, counting words, finding the longest line, parsing, etc. are all *particular instances* of this schema). Then your function is:

```
let sampler_string file string_so_far =
  fold_left_lines (fun string_so_far line ->
      let first_two_letters = String.sub line 0 2 in
      string_so_far ^ first_two_letters)
    string_so_far file
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matias pointed out, it's first important to move the recursive call outside the try/with expression so it can be tail-call optimized.

However, there is a semi-standard solution for this: use [Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org).  Batteries provides an abstraction, Enums, of the concept of iterating over something.  Its IO infrastructure then provides the `BatIO.lines_of` function, which returns an enumeration of the lines of a file.  So your whole function can become this:

```
fold (fun s line -> s ^ String.sub line 0 2) "" (BatIO.lines_of file)
```

The enum will automatically close the file when it is exhausted or garbage collected.

The code can be made more efficient (avoiding the repeated concatenation) with a buffer:

```
let buf = Buffer.create 2048 in
let () = iter (fun line -> Buffer.add_string buf (String.sub line 0 2))
  (BatIO.lines_of file) in
Buffer.contents buf
```

Basically: Batteries can save you a lot of time and effort in code like this.